# Maximizing the 4 weeks of training before a fight

Tags: ps3, fight-night-round-4

In Fight Night Round 4, in the Legacy mode, how do I efficiently use the 4 weeks of training before a fight?
Is it better to start to start with Skills training or Athletics training?
Is it OK to start the fight week without 100% stamina?

I usually do one Skills training (removing 50% stamina) then two athletics trainings (one at 10% et one at 20%). I then finish three weeks with 20% stamina and use the last week to rest and retrieve 80% of stamina, starting my fight at 100%.

The issue I have is that with a single Skills training, I think I do not win enough XP, and being now approximately #30, the other boxers are more evolved than I am in stats.
Would it then be better to do Skills Tr./Rest/Skills Train./Rest to win more XP?

But then what about the Athletics trainings?
Help me with this athlete's dilemma (With all the jabs in my face, I probably don't have enough brain cells remaining... :)

Comment: @SilverM-A Thanks for the edit. Tag was there before but automatically removed by the system as not used enough. Thanks anyway. Let's see how long this one will last :)

Comment: The tag helps to know what you're talking about when we only read the title. I'll check to be sure it doesn't disappear again ;)